# Reputation needed to participate in chat

Tags: discussion, reputation, chat

I have just joined. It says that you need reputation of 20 to participate in chat rooms. My problem is that I don't know any programming. I am a beginner and here to improve and ask questions. I can't answer any questions, as I don't have enough knowledge. What to do?

Comment: Please consider that books, tutorials, and courses may be better suited for structurally learning to program. SO questions are great to fill the gaps.

Answer (score 5):

Avoid the chat rooms for now. Ask good, original questions to fill gaps in your knowledge and gain reputation when people upvote your question.

Note, however, that Stack Overflow is geared toward programmers and programming enthusiasts. If you fall into one of those categories, you will do well here. If, however, you don't currently program and don't plan to learn, this may not be the community for you.

Comment: It is important to note that there are many communities at Stack Exchange though. They may fit better in one other than stackoverflow.

Comment: Getting 200 rep in any other community also kicks in the +100 association bonus - which is more than 20 rep and allows a user to chat basically network wide.

Answer (score 5):

One thing you can do to gain reputation on Stack Overflow is to look for posts that need editing, and then suggest edits to improve them.

There are many posts on Stack Overflow with poor grammar, spelling errors, code formatting issues, or where things are worded in a way that don't quite make sense. There are also questions where the title could be edited to make it easier for other people with the same problem to find.

These posts go into a review queue and get approved or disapproved, so make sure you're edits are substantial and fix *all* of the problems!  If approved, you'll gain +2 reputation per edit.

Overall, your grammar doesn't seem too bad. I had to fix all your lowercase 'I' and capitalize all of the first letters in all of your sentences, but that's easy to master, and practicing good grammar and editing is a great exercise for any person who strives to be a good engineer.

Of course, you can always ask well-researched questions, where every upvote earns you +5 reputation. That's a good way to learn as well as to possibly gain some rep.